# Cómo hacer el motor de búsqueda de mi aplicación en django

Tags: django, buscador, asincronismo

Hola amigos Estoy haciendo mi primera aplicación web, necesito implementar un motor de búsqueda. Quiero que un usuario escriba el nombre de una ciudad para mostrar la lista de eventos en esa ciudad. Al final dejo una imagen de mi aplicación y los modelos de la base de datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
class Ciudad (models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    departamento = models.ForeignKey(Departamento)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre


class Evento (models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    fecha = models.DateField()
    hora = models.TimeField()
    lugar = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ciudad = models.ForeignKey(Ciudad)
    imagen =models.FileField(blank=True, null=True)
    #imagen =models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

Comment: Hola Ferney bienvenido. Es una pregunta muy amplia. A parte del modelo de tu BD has de incluir el codigo que hayas intentado y que no te salga, o los errores que te den. Recuerda visitar el [tour](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber más del funcionamiento de este sitio. Un saludo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo más fácil que puedes hacer es una simple consulta de tus eventos por ciudad de esta manera:

```
def busqueda(self):
   q = request.GET.get('q', '')
   eventos = Evento.objects.filter(ciudad__nombre__icontains=q)
   return render(request, 'template_busqueda.html', {'eventos': eventos})
```

Esa seria la búsqueda que necesitas actualmente, basicamente estas devolviendo un queryset de eventos filtrados por el nombre de la ciudad, sin embargo, algo más avanzado, seria para ti, lo siguiente.

```
from django.db.models import Q
def busqueda(self):
   q = request.GET.get('q', '')

   querys = (Q(ciudad__nombre__icontains=q) | Q(ciudad__departamento__nombre__icontains=q))
   querys |= Q(nombre__icontains=q)

   eventos = Evento.objects.filter(querys)
   return render(request, 'template_busqueda.html', {'eventos': eventos})
```

Con esto estas filtrando los eventos por ciudad, departamento, o por el nombre del evento.

Recuerda que en el campo de buscar, el input, debe tener un nombre igual a q, algo asi:

```
<input name="q" placeholder="Escribe el nombre de una ciudad" id="buscador">
```

Y el formulario, debe apuntar a la url del buscador, y debes decirle que envie los datos por GET, algo como:

```
<form action="url/buscador/" method="GET">
{% csrf_token %}
...
</form>
```

Cualquier pregunta, comenta.

Comment: Gracias, lo logré con sus indicaciones.